# Rails 5: What is causing the `Can't find variable: module` error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yarnpkg

I'm using Yarn to add JS modules to my Rails app.

I've added Google's markerclusterer.js. `yarn add marker-clusterer-plus`

I then imported it in `application.js.erb`: `//= require marker-clusterer-plus/src/markerclusterer.js`

It works but I see an error in the console: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: module`.

Digging into the code, I see that the offending line is:

```js
module.exports = MarkerClusterer
```

Now I'm out of my depth. I understand `module.exports` is a way of exposing code for re-use in other files. I understand it to be standard JS. So if it's standard JS what's causing the error message?

Am I using Yarn correctly? What is causing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `marker-clusterer-plus/src/markerclusterer.js` can't be used in browser until you compile it with some tool. For example you can use webpack/webpacker to compile modern version of JavaScript.

You can fix this problem in 3 different ways:
1) Use webpacker (https://github.com/rails/webpacker) to compile assets.
`import 'marker-clusterer-plus/src/markerclusterer.js';` doesn't raise any error on my machine.
2) Use CDN:
`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-marker-clusterer/1.0.0/markerclusterer.js"></script>`
This file doesn't contain `module.exports = MarkerClusterer`, so there will be no error.
3) Download https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js (This file doesn't contain `module.exports = MarkerClusterer`).
Put it into `javascripts` folder.
Put `//= require markerclusterer.js` into `application.js`